# Sinalização no chat

Tags: suporte, chat, privilégios

No chat recebi duas vezes uma 'requisição', não sei por que isso aconteceu nem o motivo.

Tirei um print, gostaria de saber o que é isso, como e quando acontece.
[image: flag]

Fui clicando nos links um deles me mandou para o historico da sala do [mathematics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) e o outro na imagem a baixo, a url era, http://chat.stackexchange.com/admin/flagged?show=all

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quando alguma mensagem recebe uma flag de spam ou abusiva no chat, todos aqueles que estão conectados no chat em qualquer sala de chat e que também têm pelo menos um total de 10000 pontos de reputação na rede Stack Exchange inteira, são notificados para lidar com a flag.

No caso dessas duas imagens que você mostrou, eu pessoalmente não vejo nada de spam ou abusivo nelas, então eu clicaria em "*invalid*".

Comment: Não sabia que tinha isso.